# Get Recent Changes for Given Build Number in Jenkins using Jenkins CLI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I would like to get recent changes list from build number to build number for given job using command prompt.

For example, I have XYZ job created in Jenkins and latest builds are 101, 102, 103, 104. Using jenkins-cli.jar, I would like to execute a command where I can get list of recent changes made between 101 to 104. I am using SVN as repository.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of the commands supported by the Jenkins CLI by visiting `http://jenkins:8080/cli`.

The Jenkins CLI provides the `list-changes` command:

```
$ java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins:8080/ help list-changes

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar list-changes JOB RANGE [-format [XML | CSV | PLAIN]]
Dumps the changelog for the specified build(s).
 JOB                         : Name of the job to build
 RANGE                       : Range of the build records to delete. 'N-M',
                               'N,M', or 'N'
 -format [XML | CSV | PLAIN] : Controls how the output from this command is
                               printed.
```

"Range of the build records to delete" should read "Range of the build records to list changes for"

For your example:

```
$ java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins:8080/ list-changes XYZ 101-104
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, it worked like charm !! But, it is showing all file which are changed but not revision number. How to get this one ?

Comment: Now I can get the revision number if I use -format XML